# Render a list with two different styles

Tags: reactjs, styles, accordion

I'm doing a FAQ page in React, I have a list that I receive questions and answers, I would like to have different styles for each one, how can I do it?

this is my code so far

List

```
const data = [
    {
      question: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet?",
      answer:
        "Tenetur ullam rerum ad iusto possimus sequi mollitia dolore sunt quam praesentium. Tenetur ullam rerum ad iusto possimus sequi mollitia dolore sunt quam praesentium.Tenetur ullam rerum ad iusto possimus sequi mollitia dolore sunt quam praesentium.",
    },
    {
      question: "Dignissimos sequi architecto?",
      answer:
        "Aperiam ab atque incidunt dolores ullam est, earum ipsa recusandae velit cumque. Aperiam ab atque incidunt dolores ullam est, earum ipsa recusandae velit cumque.",
    },
    {
      question: "Voluptas praesentium facere?",
      answer:
        "Blanditiis aliquid adipisci quisquam reiciendis voluptates itaque.",
    },
  ];
```

and this is the question container

```
<Accordion expanded={expanded === 'panel1'} onChange={handleChange('panel1')} sx={{ width: '100%', padding: '30px' }} style={{ borderRadius: 20, margin:'10px 0px' }}>
                    <AccordionSummary
                        expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
                        aria-controls="panel1bh-content"
                        id="panel1bh-header"
                        sx={{ borderRadius:10 }}
                    >

                        <div style={{ display:'flex', flexDirection:'row', alignItems:'center' }}>
                            <div> <img src={wellbeingfaq} style={{ width:'auto', height:20, marginRight:25 }}/> </div>
                            <div style={{ fontSize:'1.5em', fontWeight:'bold' }}>Wellbeing Dashboard</div>
                            
                        </div>
                        
                    </AccordionSummary>
                    
                    <AccordionDetails>
                        
                        {listFaq}
                        
                </AccordionDetails>
                    
                    
            </Accordion>
```

Comment: add one more property ```styles``` also inside your data along side ```question``` and ```answer``` and use it

Comment: But I want the question to be different from the answer